# NoMethodError in ContainerformatsController#create undefined method `yuvstreams' for #<Containerformat:0x450f560>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error, I don't know what happened, it's been working fine few days before but it's not working now. This is the code:

```
@containerformat = Containerformat.new(params[:containerformat])

if @containerformat.containerFmt == 'TS'
  @containerformat = Containerformat.new(params[:containerformat])
  @transportstream =
    @containerformat.transportstreams.build(params[:transportstream])
  @transportstream.save
  @program = @transportstream.programs.build(params[:program])
  @program.save
  @user = @containerformat.users.build(params[:user])
  @user.save

  if params[:videoCodec_id]!= nil
    @stream = @program.streams.build(params[:stream])
    @stream.videocodec = Videocodec.find(@stream.videoCodec_id)
    @stream.save
  end
  if params[:audioCodec_id]!= nil
    @stream = @program.streams.build(params[:stream])
    @stream.audiocodec = Audiocodec.find(@stream.audioCodec_id)
    @stream.save
  end

end

if @containerformat.containerFmt == 'PS'
  @programstream =
    @containerformat.programstreams.build(params[:programstream])
  @subtitle = @programstream.subtitles.build(params[:subtitle])
  @subtitle.save
  @programstream.save
  @stream = @programstream.streams.build(params[:stream])
  @user = @containerformat.users.build(params[:user])
  @user.save

  if params[:videoCodec_id]!= nil
    @stream = @programstream.streams.build(params[:stream])
    @stream.videocodec = Videocodec.find(@stream.videoCodec_id)
    @stream.save
  end
  if params[:audioCodec_id]!= nil
    @stream = @programstream.streams.build(params[:stream])
    @stream.audiocodec = Audiocodec.find(@stream.audioCodec_id)
    @stream.save
  end

end

if @containerformat.containerFmt == 'YUV'
  @yuvstream = @containerformat.yuvstreams.build(params[:avistream])
  #@subtitle = @yuvstream.subtitles.build(params[:subtitle])
  #@subtitle.save
  @yuvstream.save
  @stream = @yuvstream.streams.build(params[:stream])
  @user = @containerformat.users.build(params[:user])
  @user.save

  if params[:videoCodec_id]!= nil
    #@stream = @programstream.streams.build(params[:stream])
    #@stream.videocodec = Videocodec.find(@stream.videoCodec_id)
    #@stream.save
  end
  if params[:audioCodec_id]!= nil
    #@stream = @programstream.streams.build(params[:stream])
    #@stream.audiocodec = Audiocodec.find(@stream.audioCodec_id)
    #@stream.save
  end

end


if @containerformat.containerFmt == 'AVI'
  @avistream = @containerformat.avistreams.build(params[:avistream])
  @avistream.save
  @stream = @avistream.streams.build(params[:stream])
  @user = @containerformat.users.build(params[:user])
  @user.save

  if params[:videoCodec_id]!= nil
    @stream = @avistream.streams.build(params[:stream])
    @stream.videocodec = Videocodec.find(@stream.videoCodec_id)
    @stream.save
  end
  if params[:audioCodec_id]!= nil
    @stream = @avistream.streams.build(params[:stream])
    @stream.audiocodec = Audiocodec.find(@stream.audioCodec_id)
    @stream.save
  end
end
```

I have yuvstreams as table in my database like other tables avisteams, programstreams table.

Comment: Do you have a `has_many :yuvstreams` association defined on your `Containerformat` class?

Comment: thanks my friend thanksssssss

Comment: i missed has_many :yuvstreams in my containerformat class

Comment: but could you please tell me what's use of this association

Comment: i am newbie ,just some days before i started

Comment: I've added an answer, was a bit big for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `has_many :yuvstreams` in your `Containerformat` class.

This defines the relationship between containerformats and yuvstreams from the containerformat point of view. You can find more details in the [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for the `has_many` method. Basically though, without that you can't refer to yuvstreams from a containerformat.

One additional point on style. Typically rails uses an _ and camel case to make names more readable. So you would have `YuvStream` and `ContainerFormat` as your class name and `has_many :yuv_streams` as your association definition. Rails expects this kind of naming and can sometimes make educated guesses about things if you use it.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html is the best I think. Feel free to accept the question if it answers what you were after ;)